# why am i getting so many numbers from my array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

I'm still working on this project and I have most of my problems fixed.
The problem shows itself while using selection B, but lies in option A and sending the array to the .txt file. There are a lot of extra numbers being added to the .txt file.  When I cout, it displays the numbers in the array like it should, but in the text file it looks like this 
Anthony201910181114-8589934604445358131768008182078541176802418196927161130726102120444535893
everything before the - is correct, but all of these numbers after need to go. 
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?
Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    int Stats[6];
    char Selection;
    string Character1;
    int i;
    char keep;




    do
     {
        cout << "Hello, welcome to my character generator. Please select an option" << endl;// Menu Options
        cout << "A: Create Character Name and generate stats" << endl;
        cout << "B: Display Name and Stats" << endl;
        cout << "C: Quit" << endl;

        cin >> Selection; // Menu Selection
        cout << endl;

            if ( (Selection == 'a') || (Selection == 'A') )// if user selects a, this happens
             {
                cout << "Welcome, Before you can start your adventures you must name your character." << endl;
               do
                {
                 cout << "Please enter your a name." << endl;// prompts user to enter a name for their Caracter
                 cin >> Character1;             

                 cout << "Thank you now lets generate your stats." << endl;

                    for (i=0; i<6;i++)// I Want this to run the function GenerateScore() 6 times and input each result into the next element of Stats[6]
                        {   
                            Stats[i]=GenerateScore(); 
                        }
                    for(i=0;i<6;i++)// displays your scores to the player.
                        {
                            cout << Stats[i]<< endl;
                        }
                    cout << "would you like to keep this name and these Stats?"<< endl;
                    cout << "Y/N" << endl;
                    cin >> keep;
                    break;
                 }
                    while ( (keep=='n') || (keep=='N') );


                ofstream savecharinfo("charactersave.txt");// saves the Name and the filled array Stats[6] to the charactersave.txt file
                    if(savecharinfo.is_open())
                    {
                        savecharinfo << Character1;
                        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
                            {
                                savecharinfo << Stats[i]; 
                            }   
                    }
                        else cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
             }
            else if ( (Selection =='b') || (Selection == 'B') )
              {

                cout << " Welcome back, here are is your character." << endl;

                ifstream displaycharacter("charactersave.txt");
                    if(displaycharacter.is_open())
                        {
                            while ( getline (displaycharacter,Character1) )
                            {
                                cout << Character1 << endl;
                            }
                                displaycharacter.close();               
                        }
                    else cout << "File could not be opened";
              }
            else
                break;
    }



while ( (Selection != 'c') || (Selection == 'C') ); // ends the program is c or C is entered.
return 0;
}       

int GenerateScore()
{
    int roll1 = rand()%6+2;
    int roll2 = rand()%6+2;
    int roll3 = rand()%6+2;
    int sum;

       sum=roll1+roll2+roll3;


      return sum;
}
```

Comment: I have a strong suspicion `while ( (keep='n') || ('N') );` wasn't what you meant.

Comment: @chris agreed. Won't it always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @Mauren Yes.  `'N'` is non-zero.

Comment: Never mind, it was working until I added the break, now it just goes back to the menu. Should I be using another if else statement to control this segment?

Comment: @geno84 - You should learn to use toupper() instead of writing condictions that check for both lower and upper case characters.  For example `while ( (Selection != 'c') || (Selection == 'C') );`.  This is confusing and probably wrong.  It can be simplified to this: `#include <ctype.h>` `while ( toupper(Selection) != 'C) );`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I will learn how to use toupper() for future projects thank you for pointing this out. Using the while () does work for this purpose and was taken form one of my previous assignments with menu selections. The course has been super rapid so a lot of things either have not stuck yet or have been covered. I've started from not knowing any code at all to this in a few weeks. Any help on the main problem addressed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Noobacode What is that? As far as I know it just simply writes to a .txt file.

Comment: @Noobacode savecharinfo is the name of the variable.  The type is ofstream.  "charactersave.txt" is the name of the file that is being written to.

Comment: `while ( (keep='n') || ('N') );` will loop forever since 'N' is true, and `keep='n'` is also an assignment that returns 'n', which is also true

Comment: also, please reformat your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned in the comments:

```
while ( (keep='n') || ('N') );
```

should (at least) be changed to

```
while ( (keep == 'n') || (keep == 'N') );
```

Also, this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; Stats[i]; i++)
```

Will only terminate when `Stats[i]` evaluates to false, which will only happen when `Stats[i] == 0`.  This loop is causing the extra chars in the file: the code keeps accessing out of bounds array elements until randomly the out of bounds element == 0.  You probably want `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`

Comment: Thank you for the fixes and explaining why. I really appreciate that. This has been a lot to take in so quickly, I don't have as good of a grasp that I would like to have.